# Ubuntu apt-get sources blocked by internet provider

Tags: apt, updates, update-manager

Every time I try to upgrade ubuntu, it gives me forbidden access. Every time that happens, Ubuntu crashes.

log file :

```
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Get:1 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ saucy/partner adobe-flash-properties-gtk i386 11.2.202.346-0saucy1 [131 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates/main libfontembed1 i386 1.0.40-0ubuntu1.1 [47.8 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ saucy/partner adobe-flashplugin i386 11.2.202.346-0saucy1 [6,600 kB]
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates/main lightdm i386 1.8.5-0ubuntu1 [107 kB]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main apturl-common i386 0.5.2ubuntu2
  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates/main cups-browsed i386 1.0.40-0ubuntu1.1 [44.7 kB]
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates/main liblightdm-gobject-1-0 i386 1.8.5-0ubuntu1 [33.4 kB]
Fetched 6,963 kB in 19s (359 kB/s)                                             
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apturl/apturl-common_0.5.2ubuntu2_i386.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I tried to contact the internet provider but there is no support from their side. I don't have a vpn account.

Is there another solution?

Comment: Avinash Raj , am not using any proxy.

Comment: It seems like you are maybe behind a transparent proxy or something. Have you tried to open the failed URL in a browser for example as well?

Comment: hello , yes ive tried and its blocked from my ISP Provider.

Comment: i even tried to add proxy , but i dont have root permision : hs@SkyNet:~$ sudo -i echo 'Acquire::http::proxy "http://192.198.60.205:34702/";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf
bash: /etc/apt/apt.conf: Permission denied

Comment: Have you tried using a [different mirror](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors)? You should't use that one unless you're in the US anyway.

Comment: hello , sorry to say am not in the U.S

Comment: If you don't have root permissions then you can't do that; even if you switched mirrors.

Comment: Elliott Frisch , am trying to have root access using sudo adduser , but my luck runs out now..

Comment: You can't use terminal output redirection with sudo like that To change your mirror, just run `software-properties-gtk` and choose one from the drop-down list.

Comment: Also, if your ISP is being evil with a transparent proxy, there may not be a whole lot you can do by tweaking the config on a local machine.

Comment: dobey , hello , i cant run it because it has been crashed too while updating ubuntu. TypeError: argument instance: Expected GObject.Object, but got PyCapsule

Comment: It seems your installation has some problems then. Also, you can't use redirection in the terminal, with sudo, like that. You would need to run `sudo sh -c "echo 'foo' > /tmp/bar"` for example. You do have root permissions with sudo, but you were trying to redirect the output of the command run under sudo, to a file you do not have write permissions to as your regular user.

Comment: hello , thank you for trying to help , its seems same problem dont have permision and cant have the root pass (dont know how yet)